pyspark call SparkActitions on Iceberg table
On the iceberg maintenance page There is a snippet:
Table table = ...
SparkActions
    .get()
    .expireSnapshots(table)
    .expireOlderThan(tsToExpire)
    .execute();

In the pyspark SparkActions is not defined.
Where or how can I import SparkActions to use it in the pyspark?
